# Datastore Tools

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am approaching to a GAE / GWT environment, coming from the RDBMS world.

Take, for instance, MySQL. If you want to do ANYTHING with your data, you can take a MySQL manager software, like PHP MyAdmin, Mysql Workbench and so on...

The datastore viewer on the appengine backoffice looks too simple to manage a complex model, I suppose, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Are there any tools ready to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datastore viewer (in production, at http://appengine.google.com/, on the dev server at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/) is the only commonly used tool for this. Is there something in particular you want to do that it can't accomplish?

Bear in mind that the App Engine datastore is a nonrelational database. 'Tables' don't exist, there's no fixed schema, and queries like joins and group by aren't supported. This means a lot of the features you might be used to in tools like PHPMyAdmin don't apply here.

Comment: e.g. UPDATE and DELETE queries?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to setup datastore object models from your script; after doing that, you will be able to use the datastore viewer to add/edit/delete items.

Answer (score 0):

The datastore viewer on the appengine is simple to manage, but only for datastore.
Datastore is a no-sql database. It's different from MySQL.

If u want to use **MySqL-liked database**, you should think about cloudSqL.
*see the document:*https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/introduction

So.....'Tables' don't exist. Some features you might be used to in tools like PHPMyAdmin don't apply here.

Datastore have other concept, like **Kind,Entity,Property**...etc
*see the document*:https://developers.google.com/datastore/

my English is a little weak, please don't mind